# JRuby stops installing mid-process via RVM

Tags: terminal, rvm, jruby, osx-mountain-lion

I'm currently attempting to install JRuby via RVM on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. However, during the process of installation, the process seems to suddenly stop without an error. I wasn't sure whether or not the install was done, so I tried to use the `jruby` command. I received an error stating that there was no such command available. I've also tried to re-install JRuby a few times, as well.

The output from RVM looks as follows (this is a re-install):

```
MacBook-Pro:~ USER$ rvm reinstall jruby
/Users/USER/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.2 has already been removed.
Removing /Users/USER/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.2...
http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.7.2/jruby-bin-1.7.2.tar.gz - #configure
jruby-1.7.2 - #download
jruby-1.7.2 - #extract
jruby-1.7.2 - #validate
jruby-1.7.2 - #setup
Saving wrappers to '/Users/USER/.rvm/bin'.
jruby-1.7.2 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/USER/.rvm/gemsets/), this may take time ...
Making gemset jruby-1.7.2 pristine.
Making gemset jruby-1.7.2@global pristine.
```

At this point, the installation seems to suddenly end, and I'm back to `MacBook-Pro:~ USER$`.

Any ideas? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is proper flow, everything worked as expected, it did not stopped half way - it finished successfully.

Comment: The thing is, it also stopped and did the same things after showing the line `jruby-1.7.2 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/USER/.rvm/gemsets/), this may take time ...` for a few minutes. This happened the first time I installed JRuby.

There was also no message that indicated a finished installation on any of the installations. After several re-installations with the same feedback, there is still no `JRuby` command available.

Comment: it looks you do not know how to use RVM - http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm - try `rvm use jruby --default` and then just `ruby --version`

Comment: Ah! You're right, I guess I wasn't fully aware of RVM and how it works. I was also unclear on how JRuby is implemented as an entirely different version of Ruby, and as such, had to be run as a Ruby alternative. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I will say, though, that I wish JRuby gave a little bit more concrete of a confirmation that the installation had succeeded.